# Replace string unless between two points

Tags: regex, r

I have the regex need to replace all backslashes `\\` with `\"` unless the `\\` is between two dollar signs `$\\bar{x}$`.  I don't know how to say in regex replace all these unless it falls between these two characters.

Here's a string and a `gsub` that gets rid og all `\\` even inside double dollars

```
x <- c("I like \\the big\\ red \\dog\\ $\\hat + \\bar$, here it is $\\bar{x}$",
    "I have $50 to \\spend\\", "$\\frac{4}{5}$ is nice", "$\\30\\ is nice too") 

gsub("\\\\", "\"", x)

## > gsub("\\\\", "\"", x)
## [1] "I like \"the big\" red \"dog\" $\"hat + \"bar$, here it is $\"bar{x}$" 
## [2] "I have $50 to \"spend\""    
## [3] "$\"frac{4}{5}$ is nice"   
## [4] "$\"30\" is nice too"
```

What I am after is:

```
## [1] "I like \"the big\" red \"dog\" $\\hat + \\bar$, here it is $\\bar{x}$" 
## [2] "I have $50 to \"spend\""
## [3] "$\\frac{4}{5}$ is nice"   
## [4] "$\"30\" is nice too"
```

Comment: I don't think that regex is the right tool for this .. you should probably split and join on `$`

Comment: What @ExplosionPills said.  This language is at best context Free, and I'm pretty sure it's context sensitive.  The biggest problem is things like `"I have $50 to \\spend\\.   My sister has $40."`  What's appropriate there?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan That's a chance happening I'm willing to deal with.  The intended purpose is to grab academic quotes.  This may include math (and $$ is the markup method of math).  Rarely would I come across two uses of dollar signs like that.

Comment: @Explosion Pills I'm open to other methods I was looking for the most efficient.  I thought you could maybe `gsub` as I have and then look for occurrences where you have `$$` with `"\\$.+?\\$"` but couldn't connect that last dot.

Comment: I'm no R genius, but you should use something like http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strsplit.html to split the string on `"$"`, then run your existing gsub on every other resulting piece.  (0, 2, 4, etc...)  You may also want to run it on the last piece no matter what.  Then you should use http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/paste.html to put them back together.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan That may be the way to go.  Seems inelegant but if necessary I'd go that route.

Comment: I highly recommend using `strsplit(x, "$", fixed=TRUE)`.  Then when you paste it back together it's just `paste0(x, collapse="$")`

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan unless the `$` is at the end of the string

Comment: Again, I don't know R that well, but most string split libraries would split `"$"` into `["",""]`, which when pasted with `"$"`, would generate `"$"` again.

Comment: Another solution not mentioned here is the simple method from [Match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3 etc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/) You would use this simple regex: `\$[^$]*\$|(\\\\)` The left side matches expressions within two dollar signs. We ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures to Group 1 your double backslashes. These are the ones to replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the strsplit method of @FrankieTheKneeMan:

```
x <- c("I like \\the big\\ red \\dog\\ $\\hat + \\bar$, here it is $\\bar{x}$",
       "I have $50 to \\spend\\",
       "$\\frac{4}{5}$ is nice",
       "$\\30\\ is nice too") 

# > cat(x, sep='\n')
# I like \the big\ red \dog\ $\hat + \bar$, here it is $\bar{x}$
# I have $50 to \spend\
# $\frac{4}{5}$ is nice
# $\30\ is nice too

# split into parts separated by '$'.
# Add a space at the end of every string to deal with '$'
#  at the end of the string (as
#      strsplit('a$', '$', fixed=T)
#  is just 'a' in R)
bits <- strsplit(paste(x, ''), '$', fixed=T)

# apply the regex to every second part (starting with the first)
# and always to the last bit (because of the ' ' we added)
out <- sapply(bits, function (x) {
                   idx <- unique(c(seq(1, length(x), by=2), length(x)))
                   x[idx] <- gsub('\\', '\"', x[idx], fixed=T)
                   # join back together
                   x <- paste(x, collapse='$')
                   # remove that last ' ' we added
                   substring(x, 1, nchar(x) - 1)
               }, USE.NAMES=F)

# > cat(out, sep='\n')
# I like "the big" red "dog" $\hat + \bar$, here it is $\bar{x}$
# I have $50 to "spend"
# $\frac{4}{5}$ is nice
# $"30" is nice too
```

This will always have cases in which it fails (`"I have $20. \\hi\\ Now I have $30"`), so you will have to keep that in mind and test it against other strings of the format you are expecting.

Comment: Wow I tried every which ay to make Frankie's method work.  Thanks Mathematical Coffee.  I'm going to poke around with it a bit and accept.  I think regex may have been more difficult than I anticipated.

Comment: It is possible to patch my approach to make it works with `"I have $20. \\hi\\ Now I have $30"`, but it will becomes very unmaintainable.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Thank you I thought this was an easy regex.  Not so.  Works well.  +1

Answer (score 5):

If you ignore the content-dependent problem, then it is possible to do replacement with PCRE regex. (It is possible to patch it on case-by-case basis, if the `$` which doesn't denote the portion to preserve `\` has a non-ambiguous form).

### Assumes that `$` always starts and ends a non-replacement region, except for the case of the odd last `$` in the string.

Pattern (the first line is RAW regex, the second line is quoted string literal):

```
\G((?:[^$\\]|\$[^$]*+\$|\$(?![^$]*+\$))*+)\\
"\\G((?:[^$\\\\]|\\$[^$]*+\\$|\\$(?![^$]*+\\$))*+)\\\\"
```

Replace string:

```
\1"
"\\1\""
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://www.regex101.com/r/zT5aG5)
[**DEMO 2**](http://www.regex101.com/r/vW7qY3)

#### Explanation

The idea is to find the next `\` in the string that is not contained within 2 `$`. This is achieved by make sure the match always starts from where the last match left off `\G`, to ensure we don't skip over any literal `$` and match the `\` inside.

There are 3 forms of sequences that we don't replace:

- Is NOT either literal `$` or literal `\`: `[^$\\]`
- Any text in between 2 `$` (this doesn't take into account escaping mechanism, if any): `\$[^$]*+\$`
- Allow replacement of `\` after the odd last `$`: `\$(?![^$]*+\$)`

So we just march through any combination of the 3 forms of sequences above, and match the nearest `\` for replacement.

### Same assumption as above, except that `$<digit>` will not start a non-replacement region.

This will work even with this kind of string:

```
I have $50 to \spend\. I just $\bar$ remembered that I have another $30 dollars $\left$ from my last \paycheck\. Lone $ \at the end\
```

Pattern:

```
\G((?:[^$\\]|\$\d|\$(?![^$]*\$)|\$[^$]*+\$)*+)\\
"\\G((?:[^$\\\\]|\\$\\d|\\$(?![^$]*\\$)|\\$[^$]*+\\$)*+)\\\\"
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.regex101.com/r/yT7kF7)

`\$\d` is added in front of the `\$[^$]*+\$` in alternation to make the engine check for that case first.

Comment: Looks promising but can't get it to work with R: `invalid regular expression '\G((?:[^$\\]|\$[^$]*+\$)*)\\', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'`

Comment: @TylerRinker: You need to enable `perl=TRUE` http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html

Comment: @TylerRinker: Made a slight change. Please use the 2nd line. The first line is to show the actual form of the regex.

Comment: It may be an R thing but the results have a lot of dollar signs as you can see in my **EDIT** 2 above

Comment: With `R` to do replacement you do `"\\1"` not `"$1"`. Try `gsub("\\G((?:[^$\\\\]|\\$[^$]*+\\$)*)\\\\", "\\1\"", x, perl=TRUE)`. Seems to struggle with the second and fourth strings though.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: Thanks. I don't use R myself. There are some variations on whether `$` and ``\`` is used in to backreference the text captured between different flavors.

Comment: @TylerRinker: Add a bit to make it work with the case 2 and case 4.

Comment: @nhahtdh mathematical.coffee's solution worked better.  I thank you for the work you put in.  This was not an easy regex as I thought.  Thank you and +1

Comment: @TylerRinker: It's fine. I am not confident I can maintain this mess either.